# .NET 3.5 + TLS 1.1/1.2 support in Windows 10

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, tls1.2, tls1.1

.NET 3.5 did not support TLS 1.1 & 1.2 when originally released. Patches were later released for [Windows 7 SP 1 & Server 2008 R2 SP1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3154518/support-for-tls-system-default-versions-included-in-the-net-framework), [Windows 8.1 and Server 2012 R2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3154520/support-for-tls-system-default-versions-included-in-the-net-framework) and [Windows Server 2012](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3154519/support-for-tls-system-default-versions-included-in-the-net-framework). However none of these patches will install on Windows 10. They all give the message "The update is not applicable to your computer".

Is there a patch available for Windows 10? It does not seem to be already a part of Windows 10. I've confirmed this by testing an HTTPS request in a .NET 3.5 app to a server requiring at least TLS 1.1 and it fails.

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43240611/net-framework-3-5-and-tls-1-2) with good answers but a) the recommendations to make code changes don't work for me because I'd prefer to install the patch, and b) the answer that references the patches doesn't cover Windows 10.

Comment: You'd likely be better off checking Microsoft's support. Also, you note *"because I'd prefer to install the patch"*, but you might not have a choice

Comment: If there is no Windows 10 patch, it generally means the patch is already part of Windows 10.

Comment: @LexLi Generally yes, however not in this case. I've confirmed by running tests on Win 10 with a .NET 3.5 app. (question updated to reflect this)

Comment: Microsoft is your only resource for such issues, and you should come to them if you need further clarification. However, the table at the bottom of that KB article does indicate clearly Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016 are listed. "I've confirmed by running tests on Win 10 with a .NET 3.5 app" is also a weak evidence to support your claim. Show your code and let others reproduce it or they can simply point out what's wrong with your code.