# TLS 1.2 in .net framework 3.5

Tags: asp.net, tls1.2

I had .net framework 3.5 asp.net eCommerce web application using Paypal payment getway.

As paypal is updated its security to TLS 1.2 then how I will go with that.

I already, check on web server is having .net framework 4.5 and application in .net framework 3.5, TLS is not running with web app.

What should I need to do?

I'm getting exception as follow:

> Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.

Comment: Hi Lokesh. welcome to SO. Please edit your Question and make it more clear what it is you are experiencing. "TLS is not running with web app." doesn't mean much. what errors do you experience? What code/setup/configuration have you done? please update your question.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33761919/tls-1-2-in-net-framework-4-0)

Comment: .NET 3.5 is no longer supported. A 3.5 application is actually a 2.0 application and runs on the 2.0 runtime which *doesn't* have TLS 1.2. As the duplicate shows, Microsoft [released a patch](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3154518/support-for-tls-system-default-versions-included-in-the-net-framework) that allowed 3.5 applications to work with TLS 1.2 but that's just a stopgap measure. You'll have to upgrade to a fresh runtime and OS version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET Framework 3.5 and TLS 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43240611/net-framework-3-5-and-tls-1-2)