# HttpWebRequest causes https endpoint to 403 only in .NET 3.5

Tags: .net-3.5, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I'm attempting to call an api using .NET Framework 3.5

I'm trying it with `HttpWebRequest` but I've not had different results with `WebClient`

The following code works in .NET Framework 4.8, however in .NET Framework 3.5 there is a `WebException` thrown from `GetResponse()`

Code:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://abolutepathtoendpoint.aspx");
req.ContentType = "text/plain";
req.Method = "GET";
req.ContentLength = 0;

string respBody;
try
{
    using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        respBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    respBody = e.ToString();
}
```

Exception:

```
The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
```

I have also been able to get it to work by pasting the url into a brower, Postman and RestClient on .NET 7

Answer (score 0):

I spent 2 days looking for this, so wanted to link the question I was asking, to the answer I was looking for:

The issue is that the link is `https` and is secured by TLS 1.2, something not available by default in .NET 3.5

This is answered here

- VB: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44893634/14965516
- C#: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69269294/14965516

Just in case the links die the solution is as follows:

Add imports:

VB

```
Imports System.Security.Authentication
Imports System.Net
```

C#

```
using System.Security.Authentication;
using System.Net;
```

Add before creating `HttpWebRequest`

VB

```
Const _Tls12 As SslProtocols = DirectCast(&HC00, SslProtocols)
Const Tls12 As SecurityProtocolType = DirectCast(_Tls12, SecurityProtocolType)
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = Tls12
```

C#

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```

For multiple protocols

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072 | 
                                       (SecurityProtocolType)768 | 
                                       (SecurityProtocolType)192;
```

- 192: Specifies the TLS 1.0 security protocol
- 768: Specifies the TLS 1.1 security protocol
- 3072: Specifies the TLS 1.2 security protocol